# Wear os build rejected from google play store

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

I got rejected from google play store while trying to upload wear app.

The application is non-standalone wear app (companion app) the app communicate with the app and receives data normally and works fine.

The app and watch working fine with me I test it on multiple watches and working fine with me, I receive an email from google with the following:

> Issue found: Basic functionality of app isn't working as described
>
> Additional notes related to this issue:
> For example, your application does not properly sync with the phone companion app.

Is there any recommendations? how to check what google test and how fix an issue if there in the app?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Tell us more about your app

Comment: @Jabbar the app in wear os won't work unless the user logged in from the companion app (we inform the user in watch to login from the companion app), as the app, sends data to the wear, and then the wear app makes an API call to get data.
The app working fine with me and I test multiple time, but I getting this error from google when I upload the app to google play store

Comment: @walidazgear I'm reading at least 2 different developers with the same problems like you and they are still unable to push apps and updates on the Play Store for Wear OS. Probably it's worth a message on Reddit?